# Is there a faster way to run this code based on pandas apply function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running this code for creating a new column of a pandas data frame `df` based on conditions and values of other columns:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: label_dict[int(x['A'])] 
                             if x['B']==1 else 
                             label_dict[int(x['A'])] + 1,
                             axis =1 )
```

where `label_dict` is something like, just few terms for example (in reality is bigger):

```
label_dict = {1: 10, 2: 24, 3: 55}
```

The code for `df['C]` is taking several seconds (about 3) on 10^5 rows. Is there a better and faster way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed it up with `numpy` `where`

```
s=df.A.astype(int).map(label_dict)
df['C']=np.where(df.B==1,s,s+1)
```

Comment: `astype(int)` before map, might be required seeing the code :)